# jinja2 сгенерировать страницу html c изображениями

Tags: python, jinja2

Всем привет, пытаюсь сгенерировать страницу с изображениями, и не понимаю как правильно добавить изображения в таблицу, возможно все делаю не правильно.

1. собираю названия файлов из папки
2. обрабатываю названия для тега img html
3. добавляю пути к файлам в список

после чего не понимаю совсем как правильно добавить изображения по 4 в ряд, вот пример кода который я написал:

```
from jinja2 import Environment
import os


image_folder = "../folder"
image_list = []
html = """
<html>
<head>
<title>monitor_page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""

image_string = """<td><img src="{{ image_source }}"></td><td><img src="{{             
image_source }}"></td>
              <td><img src="{{ image_source }}"></td><img src="{{ image_source 
 }}"></td>"""


 def get_image_list():
     for file in os.listdir(image_folder):
         image_path = image_folder + "/" + file
         image_list.append(image_path)
     put_to_image_string()


 def put_to_image_string():
 i = 0
 images_count = len(image_list) / 4
 images_count = round(images_count)
 while i <= images_count:
    print(Environment().from_string(image_string).render(image_source=item))


 get_image_list()
```

потом сгенерированый html код хочу добавить в файл, но для начала нужно разобратся как добавлять по 4 картинки n колличество раз, n = количество картинок поделить на 4, такое количство строк нам нужно добавить, ну и понятное дело округлить до большего числа, round это делает по умолчанию. Спасибо заранее за советы и подсказки. Всем хорошего дня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#for-loop

Проще в цикле вставить tr после каждой четвертой картинки

```
from jinja2 import Environment

import glob # поиск файлов
images = glob.glob('/home/eri/Pictures/*jpg' )


HTML = """
<html>
<head>
<title>monitor_page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
{% for image_source in images %}
  <td><img src="{{ image_source }}"></td>
  {% if (loop.index % 4) == 3 %}
  </tr><tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""

Environment().from_string(HTML).render(images=images)
```

Comment: спасибо eri, поробую.

Comment: не совсем понимаю `render(images=images)` - что тут должно быть, потому что переменной как `images` у меня нет, путь к каждому изображению я беру из списка

Comment: уже разобрался спасибо

Comment: `images=images` - слева название переменной в шаблоне, справа название списка в питоне.